# How do I list children of children in a foreach loop?

Tags: razor, foreach, umbraco, nodes

So, what I'm trying to do here is dynamically create a list, and have a nested list within each list item. To make it easier to imagine, what I'm specifically doing is listing years (the child nodes), and then the months of those years (children of the years nodes), for the purpose of organizing logs.

The code I have here works so far to list the years... But I'm unsure what to do for the children of the child nodes. Do I have to call a new variable, or is there a way to do it by essentially telling it "okay, now list the children of the child you just displayed"?

Not sure if it's important, but this is in an Umbraco template.

```
<ul>
    @{
        var LogsNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("LogsLanding");
    }
    @foreach (var node in LogsNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li>
            <h2>@node.AsDynamic().Name</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    CHILDREN OF LISTED NODE HERE
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Use a new foreach,  @foreach (var childnode in node.Children) { <li>@childnode.Name</li>}

Comment: Using nested @foreach requires you to know the depth of the tree you will be traversing and repeating the code for each level which is not very flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract some of your logic into a helper method, that way you can call it from within itself passing a new parent each time.

In Umbraco there are some templates which you can use/adapt to your own needs. One such template which should pretty much solve this for you (or at least demonstrate how to achieve) is the SiteMap template which is as follows:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@* Render the sitemap by passing the root node to the traverse helper *@
<div class="sitemap">
    @traverse(@Model.AncestorOrSelf())
</div>

@* Helper method to travers through all descendants *@
@helper traverse(dynamic node)
{

    @* If a MaxLevelForSitemap parameter is passed to the macro, otherwise default to 4 levels *@
    var maxLevelForSitemap = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameter.MaxLevelForSitemap) ? 4 : int.Parse(Parameter.MaxLevelForSitemap);

    @* Select visible children *@
    var items = node.Children.Where("Visible").Where("Level <= " + maxLevelForSitemap);


    @* If any items are returned, render a list *@
    if (items.Any())
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in items)
            {
                <li class="level-@item.Level">
                    <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>

                    @*Run the traverse helper again *@
                    @traverse(item)
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```